# Using Infinispan subsystem for Resteasy Cache under JBoss Wildfly-8.1.0

Tags: jboss, resteasy, wildfly, infinispan

I have a Resteasy Web Service annotated with @Cache deployed at JBoss Wildfly-8.1.0:

```
@Cache
@Path("/commercialStructures")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CommercialStructureResource extends

  @GET
  @Path("/listGeoRegions")
  @Produces(value = { APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON })
  public List<GeographicRegion> listByParentId(@QueryParam("parentId") Long parentId) {
    (...)
```

According to Resteasy docs I need to add `org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.cache.server.ServerCacheFeature` to JAX-RS Application and change web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>server.request.cache.infinispan.config.file</param-name>
        <param-value>infinispan.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>server.request.cache.infinispan.cache.name</param-name>
        <param-value>MyCache</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Questions:

1. How are infinispan.xml and cache name related to infinispan SubSystem configurations at standalone.xml?
2. Is this the correct way to Set up REST Cache under Wildfly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

No change in web.xml is required, if you need basic caching follow the steps :

> Cache response only for GET request when response is 200 OK,
>
> Test environment : Jboss6.4 and maven 3.0

**Dependency** :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-cache-core</artifactId>
  <version>Any version after 3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code Changes** : Add singleton for ServerCacheFeature in your application class.

```
singletons.add(new ServerCacheFeature());
```

Add this **annotation** to your function :

```
@Cache(maxAge=15, mustRevalidate = false, noStore = false, proxyRevalidate = false, sMaxAge = 15)
```

> noStore can be use to enable/disable to cache resp